# Brownian motion minimisation problem

Tags: brownian-motion

Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion, let  $\sigma > 0$ be fixed and let $X_t$ be
a process with fixed beginning value $x_0$ that satisfies
$dXt = u_tdt + \sigma X_tdB_t.$

Solve
$E\left[\int_0^Tu^2dt+(X_T)^2\right] \rightarrow \min$

Hint: try a value function of the form $\phi(t)x^2$ and note that $1/(a \phi + \phi^2) =
(1/a)[1/ \phi - 1/(\phi + a)]$.

I think I need to verify the Hint with a Bellman equation to solve the problem.

I think $u$ is a function of $t$.

Comment: I do not understand what this question is asking.  What is $u$?  The way you have written the question makes it appear to be a number.  Is $u$ a function?  Are you trying to minimize the quantity in that expectation?  What does that arrow mean?